# WordPress two sidebar layout or theme

Tags: theme-development, themes, sidebar, theme-options

I am new in WordPress. I was working with Drupal for some days, before. Now, I am interested on WordPress. So, I am trying to learn it.

My problem is, in WordPress I did not find any two sidebar theme or layout. I saw, WordPress always has one sidebar (**left or right**), which lies inside `<aside>` tag. But, in Drupal there are 2 sidebars (**sidebar-left**, **sidebar-right**). But, A user or developer always has an option to choose from those, one or two sidebar he need.

Is it possible to get any theme, which can help me to make a two sidebar theme? Any blank theme also will be OK. I got one blank theme called [Blank Slate](http://wordpress.org/themes/blankslate), which is just awesome. But problem is, it has only one side bar.

In short, for my project, I need a 2 sidebar blank theme. Is it possible to get? Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Assuming you know your way around HTML it would be very easy to modify Blank Slate into becoming a 2 sidebar theme. You'd just need to create a new file, `sidebar-left.php` or something similar and add `<?php get_sidebar('left');?>` before the `<section id="content">` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your "[Blank Slate](http://wordpress.org/themes/blankslate)" starter theme:
**STEP I:** Open the `functions.php` and find the word: "register_sidebar". Inside the `blankslate_widgets_init()` function, paste the following codes just after the `register_sidebar()` ends, but inside the `blankslate_widgets_init()` function (before closing second braces - '}'):

```
register_sidebar( array (
'name' => __('Left Widget Area', 'blankslate'),
'id' => 'secondary-widget-area',
'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
'after_widget' => "</li>",
'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
```

It'll register are new sidebar area into the admin panel. And the id will be available to call it into front-end.

**STEP II:** Now, copy the `sidebar.php` and paste it and rename it into: `sidebar-secondary.php`. Now erase all the codes inside, and paste the following:

```
<aside id="sidebar" role="complementary">
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar('secondary-widget-area') ) : ?>
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area">
<ul class="xoxo">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('secondary-widget-area'); ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
</aside>
```

**STEP III:** Get into the `index.php`. You'll notice a `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` after the ending `</section>` tag. Similar to the line just add a simple line after the `<?php get_header(); ?>`, but before the starting `<section>` tag, like below:

<sub>`<?php get_header(); ?>`</sub>
`<?php get_sidebar( 'secondary' ); ?>`
<sup>`<section id="content" role="main">`</sup>

Now your layout consists of two sidebars. Rest is up to you - the mighty CSS. :)